# Weird Scanf Issue

Tags: c

I am trying to finish a homework program that compares a string with a text file, so the user can essentially search the text file for the search term (string) in the file. I'm getting there :)

However today I'm running into a very weird issue. When it asks for the term to search for I input the text, but it never ends. I could type all day long and it still asks for input. What weird issue(s) am I overlooking? Fresh pair of eyes might help :)

```
/*
 ask the user for a word
 convert user word to LOWER CASE
 open output file
 open input file
 test to be sure input file is open
 search for target word and keep count --> how??
 print results to monitor
 write results to file
 close files
 */
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main (void)
{
    //declare 
    int i =0;
    int count = 0;

    /*************************************************************
     working with arrays and strings
    *************************************************************/
    char mystring[50]; //what user puts in
    char target[50]; //the word in the file we are looking for

    printf("input your message ");
    scanf("%s", mystring);
    //printf("%s", mystring);


    /*************************************************************
     find file, write to it, output the string, end and close file
    **************************************************************/

    //define text file to use
    FILE *cfile;
    //name of file == file
    cfile = fopen("./thanksgiving_proclamation.txt", "a");

    //error handling if file does not exist
    if(cfile == NULL) printf("Cannot open file");

    /*************************************************************
             parse through file and search for string
    **************************************************************/ 
    //convert string to lowercase
    for(i = 0; i < /*strlen(mystring)*/ 500; i++)//convert to string length
    {
        if(target[i] >= 'A' && target[i] <='Z')
            //convert char between a and z into lowercase
            target[i] = target[i] + 32; //makes uppercase char
    }

    //compare our strings
    do{
        //scan through file
        fscanf(cfile, "%s", mystring);  

        //convert string to lowercase
        for(i = 0; i < /*strlen(mystring)*/ 300; i++)//convert to string length
        {
            if(mystring[i] >= 'A' && mystring[i] <='Z')
                //convert char between a and z into lowercase
                mystring[i] = mystring[i] + 32; //makes uppercase char
        }
        if(strcmp(mystring, target) == 0)
            count++;
    }while(!feof(cfile));

    //while(strcmp(target,"quit")!=0)//end loop


    //print to file
    fprintf(cfile, "%s", mystring);

    //close file
    fclose(cfile);

    //show user file has been written
    printf("\nSuccess. File has been written\n");


    printf("Press Enter to Continue...");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What happens if the user enters a string that is more than 50 characters long?

Comment: In your file open error message, you should either invoke perror or use fprintf( stderr, "blah blah: %s", strerror( errno ));

Comment: Okay, what do you mean by "it never ends"?  What exactly is happening?  There's no hint of a loop in the code handling input.  What platform are you on, and what compiler are you using?  (This could be an implementation-specific bug or issue.)

Comment: Not to mention, your error checking is bad.  Write a message to stderr, not stdout, and then quit the program.

Comment: @William, at this point we don't need to worry about it. I doubt user will be inputting a word larger than 50 chars

Comment: @David, I am just talking about the scanf part. When I hit enter to end the task of inputting a character it doesn't end, but keeps letting me input chars over and over after each 'return' I hit.

Comment: This is not what's causing your problem, but you should check the return codes of fprintf() and fclose().  Unless of course you can assume infinite heap and disk space.

Comment: This is not a valid C program, it will only work with a C++ compiler because the declaration of cfile is after a statement. In C, all declarations in a block must come before statements - move the FILE *cfile; line up before the first printf to make it correct C.

Comment: @Skizz that's not true in C99.  C99 allows declarations anywhere in the function body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think pmg has hit on the actual problem; you've opened the file in append mode, and according to my copy of H&S reading from an append stream is not permitted.  You'd have to open it "a+" (append/update) in order to read *and* write the stream.

You should always check the result of the `*scanf()` call (`fscanf()`, `sscanf()`, `scanf()`, etc.) for success *before* checking `feof()` or `ferror()`, and you should never make `feof()` the loop test condition (since it won't return true until *after* you've attempted to read past the end of the file, your loop will always execute once too many times).

I'd change your loop to something like this:

```
for(;;)
{
  if (fscanf(cfile, "%s", mystring) != 1)
  {
    if (feof(cfile)) 
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "Reached end of file!\n");
      break; // exit loop
    }
    if (ferror(cfile)) 
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "Error while reading from file!\n");
      break;
    }
  }
  /**
   * continue as before
   */
}
```

Comment: perfect. the missing '+' was the culprit. now i have to go through and figure out the rest of the project ;)

Comment: I thought the user input (typed) was the problem?

Comment: yeah it was, but this fixed it. no clue.

Answer (score 2):

You open the file in append mode:

```
cfile = fopen("...", "a");
```

and then you try to read from it.

```
fscanf(cfile, "%s", mystring);
```

For a first attempt at solving the problem, I'd try to open the file for reading, read from it inside the loop and close the file. Then open it again, this time for appending to add the `mystring` there (and `fclose` it).

Once that works, if you want to, try to see if opening in "reading and appending mode" works ...

```
cfile = fopen("...", "a+");
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need "&mystring", "mystring" is already the address of the array.

It would be better to use gets or getline.

You are reading the search string into mystring, but then you are also reading the file contents into mystring.

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question .. :)

Comment: Never use gets.  Repeat for emphasis. NEVER use gets.  fgets is fine, but gets is a buffer overflow waiting to happen.

Comment: ah right, changed it to simply 'mystring'. still doesn't solve my issue tho :(

Comment: Wow, that's the first time I've seen anybody suggest the use of gets().  As William points out, gets() is a guaranteed overflow, since it doesn't allow you to specify the size of your buffer.

Comment: This is only a homework question not an industrial grade solution. ps. how exactly does scanf prevent overflows?

Comment: Hmm. Homework assignments which teach pupils that avoiding buffer overflows is "industrial grade" stuff that they don't need to know, result in programmers who can't avoid buffer overflows. If the school doesn't want its students to be able to do that, they should teach using Java, not C.

Comment: @mgb scanf() does not prevent that either, absent non-standard format strings (on GNU, is there an %a which allocates memory for you?).  fgets() is what you want to use.

Comment: Then the solution would be to use SQLServer full text search!

Answer (score 0):

It ends when you hit `Enter` and only stores characters till a whitespace.

Comment: when i hit enter, it still allows me to input characters. this is my issue. when one hit enters it should go to the next task but in this case it just keeps on letting me hit characters, even after i hit 'enter'.

Comment: how about the print statement after scanf? does it work after you hit enter?

Comment: The print statement is commented out. Out of curiosity I ran it and it works - btw, it doesn't even compile because of the `FILE* cfile` in the middle. Maybe in some **super** *weird* way, that's the reason?

Comment: @Amarghosh, no it does not print it. Just keeps letting me input content

Comment: What compiler are you using? And this can't be C code due to the position of `FILE*`

Comment: @Jacob, I am using Terminal in Mac. I'm also pretty sure it's C code.

Comment: @Jacob: What's wrong with FILE* cfile in the middle?  It looks valid to me.

Comment: @Ken: if this is a C89 or earlier compiler, you cannot mix declarations and code.  It's legal as of C99.